Unable to animate conditionally border radius of component
I have a simple component:
const borderRadiusScale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0));

React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(borderRadiusScale.current, {
        toValue: 24,
        duration: 250,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
}, []);

<Animated.View
    style={{
        borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadiusScale.current,
        borderTopRightRadius: borderRadiusScale.current
    }}
/>

But this throws an error:
com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.double

What's going on here? I've also tried interpolating it like this:
const borderRadiusScale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0));

React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(borderRadiusScale.current, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 250,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
}, []);

<Animated.View
    style={{
        borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadiusScale.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 24],
        }),
        borderTopRightRadius: borderRadiusScale.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 24],
        })
    }}
/>

But this didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

You have to set the the useNativeDriver to true (example):
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

export default function AnimatedStyleUpdateExample() {
  const borderRadiusScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(borderRadiusScale.current, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1250,
        useNativeDriver: true, // set to true
      })
    ).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          borderColor: '#ff0000',
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          borderWidth: 3,
          borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadiusScale.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 24],
          }),
          borderTopRightRadius: borderRadiusScale.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 24],
          }),
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

